# Column has a number in it, very few rows have text mixed in, can I create a new number column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that has a column that has the cost of a product, but some (very few) rows have text mixed in the column.

Would it be possible to create a new column, of a decimal type, and populate it with the other column and just ignore the rows with the 'bad' data in it?

I know I can do this via code, but was hoping I could do it with a sql query some how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a case to cast only the integer columns.  This would return NULL for non-numeric columns:

```
select 
    case when isnumeric(col1) = 1 then cast(col1 as int) end
from YourTable
```

Or you can just ignore the non-numeric columns:

```
select *
from YourTable
where isnumeric(col1) = 1
```

Comment: I am getting: Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric.
I did: when isnumeric(pricetext) = 1 then  costPrice / cast(priceText as decimal)

Comment: +1, ISNUMERIC() is the way to go.  @Blankman, this is valid working code, I tested it on my system. What data type is `costPrice`? show your query and list column datatypes. my test case: `declare @YourTable table (RowValue varchar(10), x int);INSERT INTO @YourTable VALUES ('ZZZ',2);INSERT INTO @YourTable VALUES ('123',2);INSERT INTO @YourTable VALUES ('1A23',2);INSERT INTO @YourTable VALUES ('AAA',2);select case when isnumeric(RowValue) = 1 then cast(RowValue as int)/x end from @YourTable`

Answer (score 2):

Yes what you are asking is possible to do.

**Step 1: Add a new column**

Add a decimal (9, 2) column (PriceOfItem) to your table (ItemPrices)

**Step 2: Run this query (change object names as required)**

```
Update ItemPrices
Set PriceOfItem = Convert (Decimal (9, 2), PriceText)
Where 1=1
AND IsNumeric (PriceText) = 1
```

Comment: I'm interested to know why you have "1=1" in the WHERE clause? It equates to true and would be optimised out.

Comment: @Tony: It is purely for ease of coding. If I have multiple `AND` clauses, and I have to comment them out or indent them, it is real easy. Try commenting out various parts of a `WHERE` with 3 `AND` parts to it, with and without a '1=1` and you will see what I mean.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I see what you mean, it makes it easy to remove parts of the clause.

Answer (score 0):

How does this sound? I use it all the time.  Simple & quick.

```
NewColumn: iif(
               isnumeric([OldColumn]),
               cdbl([OldColumn])
           )
```

Comment: SQL Server does not support `iif`